# Manipulator widget appearing where the 3d cursor is

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

Something weird is happening where the manipulator arrows moves where ever the 3D cursor is. I don't want this. [image: manipulator widget placement]

Comment: You have set the Pivot point to the 3D cursor

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise A quick search would have found a duplicate and saved you answering :)

Comment: Yeah . . . should have done that.

Answer (score 6):

You have set the *Pivot Point* to the *3D Cursor*:

[image]

Simply go to the menu and select whichever you want to use (most likely *Median Point*).