# Transform manipulator is no longer in center of selection

Tags: selection-tools, 3d-manipulator

I am new to Blender and i have a very frustrating issue. I find it difficult to get used to all the shortcuts so i may have pressed something i didn't mean to :

[image: This is how i want it to be]
[image: This is how mine is]

XYZ axis should be in the center of the object / face / vert (like in the first picture), not in the center of the 3D cursor (like mine is in the 2nd picture).
How can i achieve that ? And how can I return it back ?

Comment: You could try the factory settings button in "File"? Sorry if you already did

Comment: Most likely you pressed `.` (period) button; this changes the [Pivot Point](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) to 3D Cursor. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/manipulator-widget-appearing-where-the-3d-cursor-is, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8604/transforms-moving-around-the-3d-cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes, an easy fix.

To fix this problem click the small button on the bottom of the screen, in your case it should look like this: [image: Pivot point]

Click on the button and click the default, "Median point" [image: Median point]

Your manipulator should be fixed then.